# saaj exception - Unable to parse content type: null

Tags: web-services, saaj

I'm fairly new to webservices and working through a SAAJ example of sending and recieving attachments (binary files).  I can get it to work when the client sends the file but not when it requests it.  I get an exception on the client side:
ERROR:  'Content is not allowed in prolog.'
24-Oct-2012 13:59:28 com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.EnvelopeFactory createEnvelope
SEVERE: SAAJ0511: Unable to create envelope from given source
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Unable to create envelope from given source

Anybody have any ideas???my client code is as follows:

```
SOAPConnectionFactory scf = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
SOAPConnection con = scf.createConnection();
SOAPFactory soapFactory = SOAPFactory.newInstance();
MessageFactory mf = MessageFactory.newInstance();

SOAPMessage msg = mf.createMessage();
SOAPHeader header = msg.getSOAPHeader();
header.detachNode();

SOAPBody body = msg.getSOAPBody();
Name bodyName = soapFactory.createName(
"remoteOpen", "remoteOpen", 
"http://schemas.remoteOpen.com/remoteOpen");
SOAPBodyElement bodyElement = body.addBodyElement(bodyName);
SOAPElement projectName = bodyElement.addChildElement("projectName");
projectName.addTextNode("filename");

msg.saveChanges();

// create the endpoint and send the message
URL endpoint = new URL("http://localhost:8080/RemoteSaveProject/OpenServlet");
SOAPMessage response = con.call(msg, endpoint);
con.close();

SOAPBody responseBody = response.getSOAPBody();
SOAPElement ackElem = (SOAPElement)responseBody.getFirstChild();
String acknowledgement = ackElem.getValue();
```

the server code looks like this:

```
MimeHeaders mimeHeaders = new MimeHeaders();
Enumeration en = request.getHeaderNames();
while (en.hasMoreElements()) 
{
     String headerName = (String)en.nextElement();
     String headerVal = request.getHeader(headerName);
     StringTokenizer tk = new StringTokenizer(headerVal, ",");
     while (tk.hasMoreTokens()){
          mimeHeaders.addHeader(headerName, tk.nextToken().trim());
     }
}
SOAPMessage message = mf.createMessage(mimeHeaders, request.getInputStream());
SOAPBody body = message.getSOAPBody();

Name bodyName = soapFactory.createName(
                "remoteOpen", "remoteOpen", 
                "http://schemas.remoteOpen.com/remoteOpen");

        Iterator projects = body.getChildElements(bodyName);
        SOAPElement project = (SOAPElement)projects.next();
        Iterator projectNameIter = project.getChildElements(soapFactory.createName("projectName"));
        SOAPElement projectNameEle = (SOAPElement)projectNameIter.next();
        String projectName = projectNameEle.getValue();
        File file = new File(projectName);

        SOAPMessage reply = mf.createMessage();
        SOAPHeader header = reply.getSOAPHeader();
        header.detachNode();
        SOAPBody replyBody = reply.getSOAPBody();
        SOAPBodyElement bodyElement = replyBody.addBodyElement(soapFactory.createName("ack"));
        bodyElement.addTextNode("OK");

        DataHandler dh = new DataHandler(new FileDataSource(file));
        AttachmentPart attachment = reply.createAttachmentPart(dh);
        attachment.setContentId("123");
        reply.addAttachmentPart(attachment);
        reply.saveChanges();

        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        putHeaders(reply.getMimeHeaders(), response);

        response.setContentType("text/xml");
        ServletOutputStream replyOS = response.getOutputStream();
        reply.writeTo(replyOS);
        replyOS.flush();
        replyOS.close();
```

putHeaders looks like:

```
Iterator it = headers.getAllHeaders();

    while (it.hasNext()) 
    {
        MimeHeader header = (MimeHeader) it.next();
        String[] values = headers.getHeader(header.getName());

        if (values.length == 1) 
        {
            res.setHeader( header.getName(), header.getValue());
        } 
        else 
        {
            StringBuffer concat = new StringBuffer();
            int i = 0;

            while (i < values.length) 
            {
                if (i != 0)
                {
                    concat.append(',');
                }
                concat.append(values[i++]);
            }
            res.setHeader(header.getName(), concat.toString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you post correct client side code? Which line throws an error (`SOAPMessage response = con.call(msg, endpoint);`)?

Comment: it is the correct client side code, although it looks like it originates from the server side....it happens at the point of:  SOAPMessage response = con.call(msg, endpoint);

Comment: If the error is thrown on that line it means that the server received the request, processed it and returned a response already. The error indicates that the data/message returned by the server is not of the expected format. Try to connect to the server via telnet and check the response - is it well formatted and does it contain all information you expect?

Comment: that makes sense, when I added a line to set the content type to be application/octet-stream it blew up again but with a different message:
SEVERE: SAAJ0537: Invalid Content-Type. Could be an error message instead of a SOAP message

Comment: is there any examples around of a servlet attaching a binary file to SOAP reply?

Comment: I've changed the server code slightly (modified original code above) and I'm now getting a different exception:
ERROR:  'Content is not allowed in prolog.'
24-Oct-2012 13:59:28 com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.EnvelopeFactory createEnvelope
SEVERE: SAAJ0511: Unable to create envelope from given source
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Unable to create envelope from given source

Anybody have any ideas???

Comment: Did you try what I suggested? Did you check what format the server returns? It is likely that the server returns correct data, but your client is not providing correct mapping for the data returned by the server... Or are you expecting a different answer? Then post your expected answer and maybe somebody will give that to you...

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Google app engine, like me, the problem is that GAE doesn't support `com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.packaging.mime.internet.ParameterList` which is used internally somewhere in the call chain of `javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnection.call()`. So you must use a workaround.

I personally did it by using `java.net.HttpURLConnection` instead of `javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnection` and manually sending and parsing SOAP messages.